# Test Exchange 2010 connectivity programmatically with C#

Tags: exchange, monitoring, exchange-2010, windows

Other than a simple ping, I'm looking for ways to connect to Exchange just for monitoring purposes. Should I connect to a Web Service? WMI?

I'm merely trying to test that the Exchange server is up and running. A ping doesn't tell me enough. I've found plenty of different ways to do this but none of them jump out and scream at me that it's the best.

Comment: Are you trying to do up/down monitoring of Exchange services?

Comment: Maybe try and connect to EWS?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: @DougLuxem - That's precisely what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Zoredache - Thanks. I had that one bookmarked and will take a closer look.

Comment: There are many excellent monitoring packages out there that will do this for you (many of which are open source). There is no need to reinvent the wheel and code it yourself.

Comment: @Bryan I agree, but in this case I'm tying it in to a SharePoint Web Part and I felt that what I was doing was far too simple to need an outside solution. I figured there was going to be consensus on a 'best practice' of checking Exchange status, but that doesn't appear to be the case (probably didn't help that my question -- 1st one on this site -- was shutdown within minutes of submitting with no opportunity to reopen or clarify). No matter, I'll likely go the EWS route and be done with it.

Comment: @silmaril8n I'm guessing that the question was closed before you edited it to revision 2 - it's hard to tell with the fuzzy timings displayed here on SF. I voted to re-open when I posted my last comment, but if I were you, to improve the chances of getting it re-opened, I'd try and add some additional info to your question, e.g. what have you found so far. (although I do personally think the question is a perfectly reasonable question to ask in its current form).

Answer (score 0):

All of the above- depending on the stuff you are trying to monitor.  What specifically are you trying to check?

Comment: I'm really trying to verify that Exchange is alive and functioning in a relatively basic sense. Nothing too deep, but more than just checking that the actual server is online.